# Symfony2 SoapClient set up using besimple/soap-client

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, soap, wsdl

In my Symfony2 project I am trying to call Web Service, i did some googling anf found this SOAP Bundle `besimple/soap-client`. I installed it and did some configurations:

**Config.yml**:

```
be_simple_soap:
      clients:
        TestWebService:
          wsdl: https://mywebservice.svc?wsdl
```

**Services.xml**:

```
<!-- Soap Client -->
<service id="mybundle.test.soap.wrapper"
         class="MyBundle\Test\Soap\SoapClientWrapper">
    <argument key="soap_options">%be_simple_soap%</argument>
</service>
```

I then injucted this service into one of my Dto/Template this wortks fine no errors.

When i navigate to my Template where i injected SOAP service i get this error:

```
{
    errors: {
        code: 500,
        message: "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '/Users/my.name/Dev/test-api/src/MyBundle/Test/Soap\'"
    }
}
```

Any suggestions guys i find it hard to find anything on `Google`.

Comment: The Service should be called and handled for Exceptions in the Controller Action, not the Template directly. Then you would handle the exception and may redirect to an error action or render an error template.

Comment: Also, the wsdl location doesn't exist, the wsdl xml is invalid or an invalid wsdl location, or content is cached.

Comment: @mblaettermann yep I know i can do that but that still does not explain why i get this error, i am trying to find the root of the problem.

Comment: @Flosculus this is the wsdl i am using, I placed it under Soap/wsdl `http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL` and SoapClientWrapper.php sits in the root of Soap dir which loads all the files from WSDL dir

Comment: You might want to debug closer to the library so you can make sure its using the correct path.

Comment: Hmmm correct me if am wrong guys but when I am trying to interact with ws from my codebase  i need wsdl link only. If i was crating my own ws then i would have to generate my own wsdl....?

Comment: Correct. Maybe the client lib you use isn't working correctly, as @Flosculus suggested...

Comment: Yeah.  I mean PHP "will" cache the wsdl from the link, but its strange that you are downloading it yourself.